# Error en duplicado clave foranea

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relaciones

Estoy utilizando el siguiente request para validar los datos que se envian por formulario

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'legajo'            =>  ['required','max:8', Rule::unique('empleados')->ignore($this->empleado)],
        'last_name'         =>  'required',
        'telefono'          =>  'required',
        'first_name'        =>  'required',
        'dni'               =>  ['required','max:8', Rule::unique('empleados')->ignore($this->empleado)],
        'cuil'              =>  ['required','max:13', Rule::unique('empleados')->ignore($this->empleado)],
        'cuil'              =>  ['required','max:13', Rule::unique('empleados')->ignore($this->empleado)],
        'empleado_id'       =>  ['required', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->empleado)],
        'domicilio'         =>  'required',
        'fecha_ingreso'     =>  'required|date',
        'fecha_egreso'      =>  'nullable|date',
        'carnet'            =>  'required|boolean',
        'hijos'             =>  'required|integer',
        'sexo'              =>  'required|string',
        'estado'            =>  'required|string',
        'puesto_id'         =>  'required|integer',
        'sucursal_id'       =>  'required|integer',
        'categoria_id'      =>  'required|integer',
        'localidad_id'      =>  'required|integer',
    ];
}
```

Pero cuando realizo la accion de update me sale error de clave duplicada en el campo de "empleado_id"

Controlador

```
public function update(EmpleadoUpdate $request, $id)
{
    $empleado = Empleado::find($id);

    $empleado->legajo = $request->legajo;
    $empleado->telefono = $request->telefono;
    $empleado->last_name = $request->last_name;
    $empleado->first_name = $request->first_name;
    $empleado->dni = $request->dni;
    $empleado->cuil = $request->cuil;
    $empleado->fecha_nacimiento = $request->fecha_nacimiento;
    $empleado->sexo = $request->sexo;
    $empleado->estado = $request->estado;
    $empleado->hijos = $request->hijos;
    $empleado->carnet = $request->carnet;
    $empleado->localidad_id = $request->localidad_id;
    $empleado->domicilio = $request->domicilio;
    $empleado->fecha_ingreso = $request->fecha_ingreso; 
    $empleado->fecha_egreso = $request->fecha_egreso; 
    $empleado->sucursal_id = $request->sucursal_id;
    $empleado->categoria_id = $request->categoria_id; 
    $empleado->puesto_id = $request->puesto_id; 

    $empleado->save();

    $UsuarioAsignacion =    User::find($request->empleado_id);
    $UsuarioAsignacion->empleado_id = $empleado->id;

    $UsuarioAsignacion->save();

    return redirect()->route('empleados.index')->with('info','El empleado fue actualizado correctamente');
}
```

Alguien tiene idea que puede ser?
La accion seria la siguiente, debo asignarle a un empleado un usuario creado, y unicamente un empleado puede tener un solo usuario aisgnado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolvi de la siguiente forma.
Agregue la columna usuario_id en la tabla empleados.
De esta forma evito hacer reglas de validacion en tablas cruzadas.

Request

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'legajo'            =>  ['required','max:8', Rule::unique('empleados')->ignore($this->empleado)],
        'last_name'         =>  'required',
        'telefono'          =>  'required',
        'first_name'        =>  'required',
        'dni'               =>  ['required','max:8', Rule::unique('empleados')->ignore($this->empleado)],
        'cuil'              =>  ['required','max:13', Rule::unique('empleados')->ignore($this->empleado)],
        'cuil'              =>  ['required','max:13', Rule::unique('empleados')->ignore($this->empleado)],
        'usuario_id'        =>  ['required', Rule::unique('empleados')->ignore($this->empleado)],
        'domicilio'         =>  'required',
        'fecha_ingreso'     =>  'required|date',
        'fecha_egreso'      =>  'nullable|date',
        'carnet'            =>  'required|boolean',
        'hijos'             =>  'required|integer',
        'sexo'              =>  'required|string',
        'estado'            =>  'required|string',
        'puesto_id'         =>  'required|integer',
        'sucursal_id'       =>  'required|integer',
        'categoria_id'      =>  'required|integer',
        'localidad_id'      =>  'required|integer',
    ];
}
```